# How optimize module namespace in output typescript of multiple files, use gulp

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, gulp

I encountered a problem, if use methodology: **one file - one class** in typescript project, as in the example below.

File Greeter.ts

```
module App {
    export class Greeter {
        constructor(public greeting: string) { }
        public greet() {
            return "<h1>" + this.greeting + "</h1>";
        }
    };
}
```

File Program.ts

```
module App {
    export class Program {
        private _greeter = new Greeter("Hello, world!");
        public main() {
            document.body.innerHTML = this._greeter.greet();
        }
    };
}
```

Result file

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    var Greeter = (function () {
        // class code
    } ());
    App.Greeter = Greeter;
})(App || (App = {}));

var App;
(function (App) {
    var Program = (function () {
        // class code
    } ());
    App.Program = Program;
})(App || (App = {}));
// point of entry
var program = new App.Program();
program.main();
```

As can be seen duplication declaration **App**. I would like exclude any repetition like this:

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    var Greeter = (function () {
        // class code
    } ());
    App.Greeter = Greeter;

    var Program = (function () {
        // class code
    } ());
    App.Program = Program;
})(App || (App = {}));
// point of entry
var program = new App.Program();
program.main();
```

Otherwise, when a large amount of classes, it turns out a lot of excess code in the output file.

Maybe I'm wrong somewhere?

----Update----

The project is building by **gulp-concat** and **gulp-typescript**, maybe exist package allowing avoid this?

[example on github](https://github.com/coddwrench/GulpTypeScriptExample)

Comment: not that it would solve the repetition problem so much, but maybe you could try and use `gulp-uglify` to minify the concatenated file?

Comment: @dafyddPrys, construction `var App; (function (App) {...` bad minimized, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/coddwrench/GulpTypeScriptExample/blob/master/build/min/output.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Otherwise, when a large amount of classes, it turns out a lot of excess code in the output file.
>   Maybe I'm wrong somewhere?

No. This is by design. Basically typescript allows each section to run in isolation.

## Warning

Please try and migration to modules . More https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html